# Socket.ConnectAsync for windows store application does not like Async

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, async-await

Windows store applications are frustrating to say the least; just close enough to regular .net to get into trouble.

My issue with working in Tasks, await, and Socket.ConnectAsync.

I've got the following code:

```
    public async Task<string> Connect(string hostName, int portNumber)
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        // Create DnsEndPoint. The hostName and port are passed in to this method.
        DnsEndPoint hostEntry = new DnsEndPoint(hostName, portNumber);

        // Create a stream-based, TCP socket using the InterNetwork Address Family. 
        _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        // Create a SocketAsyncEventArgs object to be used in the connection request
        SocketAsyncEventArgs socketEventArg = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        socketEventArg.RemoteEndPoint = hostEntry;

        // Inline event handler for the Completed event.
        // Note: This event handler was implemented inline in order to make this method self-contained.
        socketEventArg.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(delegate (object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
        {
            // Retrieve the result of this request
            result = e.SocketError.ToString();

            // Signal that the request is complete, unblocking the UI thread
            _clientDone.Set();
        });

        // Sets the state of the event to nonsignaled, causing threads to block
        _clientDone.Reset();

        // Make an asynchronous Connect request over the socket
        await _socket.ConnectAsync(socketEventArg);

        // Block the UI thread for a maximum of TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS milliseconds.
        // If no response comes back within this time then proceed
        _clientDone.WaitOne(TIMEOUT_MILLISECONDS);

        return result;
    }
```

And I started added in Async / await to the app to prevent UI issues.  But when I went into this function and added the Await to

```
            await _socket.ConnectAsync(socketEventArg);
```

I get the error:

Error   CS1929  'bool' does not contain a definition for 'GetAwaiter' and the best extension method overload 'WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions.GetAwaiter(IAsyncAction)' requires a receiver of type 'IAsyncAction'

In looking at the docs for ConnectAsync it looks like ConnectAsync is supposed to support await...

Does it not support await?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `ConnectAsync` is not a [TAP method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175(v=vs.110).aspx), and thus cannot be used with `await`.

My #1 recommendation for anyone using raw sockets is "don't". If you can, use a REST API (with `HttpClient`) or a `SignalR` API. Raw sockets have tons of pitfalls.

If you *must* use raw sockets (i.e., the other side is using a custom TCP/IP protocol and you don't have the power to fix the situation), then the first thing to note is that the `Socket` class has three complete APIs all in one class.

The first is the deceptively simple-looking synchronous API (`Connect`), which I do not recommend for any production code. The second is the standard APM pattern (`BeginConnect`/`EndConnect`). The third is a specialized asynchronous pattern that is specific to the `Socket` class (`ConnectAsync`); this specialized API is much more complex to use than the standard asynchronous API, and is only necessary when you have chatty socket communication in a constrained environment, and need to reduce the object churn through the garbage collector.

Note that there is no `await`-compatible API. I haven't spoken to anyone at Microsoft about this, but my strong suspicion is that they simply thought the `Socket` class had too many members already (3 complete APIs; adding an `await`-compatible one would add a fourth complete API), and that's why it was skipped over when they added TAP-pattern (`await`-compatible) members to other types in the BCL.

The correct API to use - easily 99.999% of the time - is the APM one. You can [create your own TAP wrappers (which work with `await`) by using `TaskFactory.FromAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178(v=vs.110).aspx#ApmToTap). I like to do this with extension methods, like this:

```
public static Task ConnectTaskAsync(this Socket socket, EndPoint remoteEP)
{
  return Task.Factory.FromAsync(socket.BeginConnect, socket.EndConnect, remoteEP, null);
}
```

You can then invoke it anywhere on a `Socket`, as such:

```
await _socket.ConnectTaskAsync(hostEntry);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not connecting to a REST API (unfortunately).  The Windows Store API has been very difficult to find working (workable) classes.  I didn't know signalR works with it; I'll take a look at it and see if it fits what I'm doing.  Thanks, Stephen.

Comment: @DaBlue: It's actually the `Socket` class that's weird in this way. It has the same problems on the desktop framework.

Comment: I was hopeful on signalr, but that will not work.  I pulled a class I wrote into the universal windows (I had some converting to do) just to figure out it won't connect to a socket that is not a signalr server.  I'm now looking at streamsockets.

Comment: With Core (netcoreapp1.0) I am having trouble finding a public socket.BeginConnect.  Structures exist in net451.  Assume there a dependency I am missing.

Comment: @MatthewYoung: Interesting. [It looks like](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/System.Net.Sockets/4.1.0/netstandard1.3/doc/System.Net.Sockets.Socket) `Socket` on netcore only supports the `SocketAsyncEventArgs` API. There are [TAP wrappers available](http://dotnetapis.com/pkg/System.Net.Sockets/4.1.0/netstandard1.3/doc/System.Net.Sockets.SocketTaskExtensions), though - I'd just use those.

Comment: Just odd that core deviates.  There is a shift to go purely async and not map with the rest of the Net flora.  Also, netstandard1.3 had BeginConnect so the link to the documentation can't align with netstandard1.3 rather a later version of core.

Comment: @MatthewYoung: `Socket` is unusual even on desktop. It supports APM and SAEA in addition to sync APIs. `Socket` on core appears to support TAP and SAEA in addition to sync APIs. The docs I linked to are autogenerated from the actual reference dlls, so there's no `BeginConnect` on `netstandard1.3` that I can see.